# Does difference in population of men and women create problems?

Tags: women, men-male

How does Judaism view the sexual demography of the world in terms of that principle that each one must seek a partner in order not to feel alone as determined by God in Genesis?

I know that various Jewish authorities no longer consider marriage an obligation for Gentiles but that principle of solitude is a strong voice against remaining single.

The UN says that there are more men than women in the world, in Brazil where I live there are 5 million more women than men, there is no polygamy anymore except in some Islamic countries, so this demographic difference does not create theological problems for what was it intended? Because the way God put it in Genesis there forward every man would have a woman and that was disturbed, that principle was reformulated and if not what would fix it, in some places women demanding men in default and in other places men demanding women in deficiency .

In Judaism how is this distribution and if Judaism deals with it since it is an obligation to marry, if there is a difference in the population of the genders this obligation is disturbed.

Comment: An imbalance between men and women just means it's slightly harder for one side to find an ideal partner. Until there's a scenario where every man is married I don't see the halachic dilemma.

Comment: How is it not a problem? Does every Jew up to the age of 20, which is the religiously legal age, have enough Jewish women to go around? Otherwise, they will have to marry later for the younger ones to be of marriageable age or wait for someone to divorce and be free.

Comment: There's no halacha that the entire population of Jews must be married. It's a requirement on the individual. So long as there's one available woman for *you* to marry, the question is moot.

Comment: But I didn't question the population, but the theological implication of there being more men or women for this to imply some social-religious disorder, which makes no difference since both men and women in Judaism must marry, you will agree that neither Will all Jews be able to marry at the age recommended or even required by some authorities? I don't know how the distribution is specifically for Jews, also because of mixed marriages which should make it even more difficult but it shouldn't be different from the rest of the world and there must be some difference

Comment: Obviously an imbalance is a problem, but what can be done about it?

Comment: Wouldn't this have theological implications, such as certain people not being able to fulfill certain commandments, such as not being able to marry due to the lack of a compatible spouse? It's complicated to assess the population, individually it doesn't seem to be a problem, it's a macro issue, someone will be impacted, the account doesn't close. Before there was war, there were more women than men and polygamy somehow kept the thing on a tightrope

Comment: There is no obligation for a woman to get married. If a man cannot find a wife then one doesn't get married. What are the other solutions?

Comment: Is there an option for a Jew not to marry? This problem also affects them, no one is escaping. Individually a Jewish man will find a wife but macro this problem of demographic gender difference affects someone because the account does not close, I don't know how many Jewish men in relation to Jewish women there are, practicing Jews, secular people will not see this as a problem, Practitioners, if they have a quantitative distortion someone will be affected, being men there is an imperative to marry and even the age to marry, if it passes it is alleged that you are already in sin.